# DrawnObject will not move with mouse within timer

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a project to try and make a bar follow my mouse from side to side in a picture box using a timer. Also need to take into how fast I move my mouse in consideration. I tried doing this code below by my rectangle won't move? Why?

```
Dim p as rectangle

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
  Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics
  g = e.Graphics

  Dim PaddleSize As New Size(50, 10)
  Dim MystartingPoint As New Point(225, PictureBox1.Height - 50)
  p = New Rectangle(MystartingPoint, PaddleSize)
  g.FillRectangle(Brushes.OliveDrab, p)       
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  p.Location = Me.PointToClient(New Point(MousePosition.X - 25, PictureBox1.Height - 50))
  pictureBox1.refresh()    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your edit removed the question so I rolled it back.  If you are trying to move a label, that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting point never changes (it's always at 225 x height - 50) since you ignore the information in the tick event.

My guess is you are trying to make a paddle go back and forth on the screen with the mouse move, so try something like this:

```
Private p As Point

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) _
  Handles PictureBox1.Paint
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.OliveDrab, New Rectangle(p, New Size(50, 10)))
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
  Handles Timer1.Tick
  p = New Point(PictureBox1.PointToClient(New Point(MousePosition.X - 25, 0)).X,
                PictureBox1.Height - 50)
  PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

You don't want to include the `PictureBox.Height - 50` in the PointToClient calculation since you really do want the paddle to always be 50 pixels from the bottom of the control.